# How can I use the WriteMessage(Stream stream) method of the MessageBuffer object in .NET WCF?

Tags: .net, wcf, serialization, soap, xmldocument

In trying to figure out how to convert a .NET System.ServiceModel.Channels.Message object into an XmlDocument, I thought I could do this:

```
Message message = Message.CreateMessage(messageVersion, "SOAPAction");

using(var messageBuffer = message.CreateBufferedCopy(int.MaxValue))
{
    var stream = new MemoryStream();
    using(var xmlWriter = XmlWriter.Create(stream))
    {
        var xmlDocument = new XmlDocument();

        messageBuffer.WriteMessage(stream);
        stream.Flush();

        stream.Position = 0;
        xmlDocument.Load(stream);
        stream.Close();

        Debug.Writeline(xmlDocument.OuterXml);
    }
}
```

However, this results in an error on the xmlDocument.Load(stream):

```
"Data at the root level is invalid. Line 1, position 1."
```

I now realize I should be using the WriteMessage of the Message object in conjuction with an XmlWriter object like this:

```
Message message = Message.CreateMessage(messageVersion, "SOAPAction");
using(var messageBuffer = message.CreateBufferedCopy(int.MaxValue))
{
    var stream = new MemoryStream();
    using(var xmlWriter = XmlWriter.Create(stream))
    {
        var xmlDocument = new XmlDocument();

        messageBuffer.CreateMessage().WriteMessage(xmlWriter);
        xmlWriter.Flush();
        stream.Flush();

        stream.Position = 0;
        xmlDocument.Load(stream);

        xmlWriter.Close();
        stream.Close();

        Debug.WriteLine(xmlDocument.OuterXml);
    }
}
```

I'm sure I'm missing some fundamental point, but this leads me to my question - what use is the WriteMessage(Stream stream) on the MessageBuffer object?